# ASP.Net 4.0 image select and change source

Tags: asp.net, image, select

If I have a set of image (buttons) or even just plane images, 5 in a row, and I want to achieve the following, what would be the easiest way, I can't realy find a good solutions to this:

- On clicking either of the images, it needs to get a new src, but others need to be restored to the original state.
- A Asp:Label needs to be set on clicking, based on the image clicked
- On doing a PostBack, I need to know which one is selected

Asside from this, it's asp.net 4.0, so single quotes are giving me javascript pain.

Comment: its a big application. will take time. you are not asking a question. Even asking for a whole application.

Comment: Oh no, don't interprete it like that please. I'm not asking for a block of finished code. I'm just asking what the best practise would be.

Comment: do you know, how to mark an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On clicking either of the images, it needs to get a new src, but others need to be restored to the original state.**

1. First of all you have to create a function in which you will set all 5 images to the original state.
2. Then be sure to give same class name to each image element.
3. After that crate a function which will fire according to class name like

   ```
       $(".classname").click(function(){

      //first call the function which will set all 5 images to original state.

      //then change the source of the current image. onwhich user has clicked as below:

       $(this).attr("src","new source");
      // here you can store the id of current image in a variable to keep the record which images have  been clicked
     });
   ```

**A Asp:Label needs to be set on clicking, based on the image clicked**

you can easily set the Asp:Label in above function. If you are familiar with javascript code. Its too simple to set.

**On doing a PostBack, I need to know which one is selected**

After creating the first `function` your rest of two steps get completed them selves.

in above `function` you have saved the IDs of images on which a user has clicked in a `variable`.

on doing `postback` you can easily save the `varibale's` data in `hiddenfield` or assign it to static `varibale` or what ever the way you like.

at last you can access it in `code behind`.

If i have to do this thing. i'll follow the above process. Its far easy and fast process. Everything can be done at client side.

what you think?

Comment: I made a start with javascript but got stuck on asp.net 4.0 not handling single quotes. I know i can write my own htmlwriter, but was figuring if that was the way to go. 

The thing that has me the most in above solution, is wether or not it is best practice to do this all in javascript... But, I'm surely gonna retry this setup, as it seems a fast way indeed. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: what you mean by "asp.net 4.0 not handling single quotes"? please provide the code. btw you asked for the "best practise". and i ahve given you the best way to do this job. Rest is up to you, you are getting some problems in code. If my answer helps you(not in code). then mark it as answer. it can help others.

Comment: you should do it with javascript. this kind of work required client side implementation. if you will try it at server side. It must be unrealistic to think, do and see.

Comment: asp.net has some issue going on with attributes.add handling quotes.
The rest of your answer is handling my issue very well, thank you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013912/asp-net-single-quotes-are-converted-to-39